# Considering the result of CV_IMAGE_ELEM as QString?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I want to display the results of the 10x10 window CV_IMAGE_ELEM in a LineEdit whose arguments are QString.

Shall I consider the following:

```
for (int y=0;y<10;y++)
{
    for (int x=0;x<10;x++) //width
    {
        QString qstr= CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img_crop_mat, uchar, y, x*3+ 2);
        QString ctot= qstr + ctot;
        lineEdit_mat->setText(ctot + " ");
    }
    lineEdit_mat->setText("\n");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you getting? Is it working?

Comment: No, it gives nothing. Blank lineEdit !

Comment: You are setting the text to "/n" so what did you expect?

Comment: @Roku  OK, what if I want to insert an end line and add some other texts to the LineEdit? Possible?

Comment: Can you tell me please?

Comment: without lineEdit_mat->setText("\n"); wat are you getting?Is it displaying what you want other than the line break problem?

Comment: @Vinod Paul Without the \n its not really displaying what I want because I want that, in every time the x loop has finished, it ends the line and start in a new line. In total, I would like to have values in rows and columns. It even avers that when doing setText(cot + "\n"), it doesn't recognize the endline !!!

Comment: A line edit displays a single line of text. You want QTextEdit/QTextBrowser. And use append, not setText.

Comment: yes, if the problem is only with line breaks,then u shud use qtextedit as frank said

Answer (score 0):

Try looping

```
myQString.append(QString("%1 ").arg((int) IPL_IMAGE_ELEM(...) ));
```

This is assuming you want to print the image data in a numerical format.